# convert LatLng into Pixel compatible to Android Screen

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map image in which a location for example "New York" is marked & i have converted its latitude and longitude into pixel , using javascript example of Google Map Javascript API V3 [click](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latlng-to-coord-control/latlng-to-coord-control.html)

but the problem is ANCHOR_OFFSET_ as i want the pixel to be converted according to Android screen. so basically what i am trying to implement is if i have location (lat , lng ) - on google map image - i want to convert it into (X,Y) co-ordinates of android screen.

Answer (score 10):

If your using a MapView then you can call something like:

```
//Get map projection
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

//Convert LatLng to on screen location
Point p1 = new Point();
//projection.toPixels(gp, p1);
p1 = projection.toScreenLocation(location);
```

where `location` is a LatLng. resulting with point `p1` containing the screen location, the screen location is in screen pixels (not display pixels) relative to the top left of the map (not of the whole screen).

Comment: i am rendering Google Map into WebView so i am not using MapView , do have another approach ?

Comment: I'm using the Projection class https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection but there is no method toPixels, am I using wrong class? If yes what is the correct?

Comment: @ademar111190 just edited the answer, post is almost 5 years old now so api must have changed at some point.